# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 44 Column: 30

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT r.llobjid   AS dataid, 
                                r.drawingid, 
                                r.revisionid, 
                                r.revisionnumber AS Revision_Number, 
                                r.revisionlabel, 
                                r.minorrevisionlabel, 
                                r.revisiontype, 
                                p.project AS Project, 
                                r.revisionstatus, 
                                r.r1i AS SignIn_Requestor, 
                                r.r2i AS SeedFileVersion, 
                                rt.display_type_name AS Revision_Type, 
                                rt.can_signin, 
                               rs.display_status_name AS Revision_Status, 
                                a.adntypeid, 
                                at.NAME AS ADN_Type, 
                                a.requestby, 
                                a.assignbyAS Assign_By_Id, 
                                ' '  AS Assign_By, 
                                a.assigndate, 
                                ' ' AS Assign_Date 
                FROM   adnids a 
                       INNER JOIN crt_revision r 
                               ON r.drawingid = a.adnid 
                                  AND Upper(a.wholeid) LIKE '4160%' 
                       INNER JOIN adntypes at 
                               ON a.adntypeid = at.adntypeid 
                                  AND at.orgunitid = 21 
                       INNER JOIN crt_project p 
                               ON r.projectid = p.projectid 
                                  AND p.ouid = 21 
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN crt_revision_type_map rt 
                                    ON r.revisiontype = rt.revtypeid 
                                       AND rt.ouid = 21 
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN crt_revision_status_map rs 
                                    ON r.revisionstatus = rs.revstatusid 
                                       AND rs.ouid = 21 
                WHERE  ( r.revisionstatus = 2 )) tbl1 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT d.dataid  AS LLDataID, 
                         Cast(d.dcomment AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS 
                                           Title, 
                                           d.NAME  AS Document_Name, 
                                       d.createdate  AS  Created_Date, 
                                       d.modifydate  AS Modified_Date, 
                                           d.subtype, 
                                           d.versionnum, 
                                           d.permid, 
                                           d.reserved, 
                                           d.ownerid 
                           FROM   crt_revision r3 
                                  INNER JOIN adnids a3 
                                          ON r3.drawingid = a3.adnid 
                                      AND Upper(a3.wholeid) LIKE '4160%' 
                                  INNER JOIN dtree d 
                                          ON r3.llobjid = d.dataid 
                           WHERE  ( r3.revisionstatus = 2 )) tbl2 
                       ON tbl1.dataid = tbl2.lldataid 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT l.dataid AS asm_dataid, 
                                                l.stateid, 
                                                l.intransition, 
                                               ls.NAME  AS Current_State, 
                                                ls.signin, 
                                                ls.lifecycleid, 
                                                ll.NAME  AS Lifecycle 
                                FROM   crt_revision r5 
                                       INNER JOIN adnids a5 
                                               ON r5.drawingid = a5.adnid 
                                    AND Upper(a5.wholeid) LIKE '4160%' 
                                       INNER JOIN lm_lifecycles l 
                                               ON l.dataid = r5.llobjid 
                                       INNER JOIN lm_def_states ls 
                                               ON l.stateid = ls.stateid 
                                       INNER JOIN lm_def_lifecycles ll 
                                               ON ls.lifecycleid = 
                                                  ll.lifecycleid 
                                WHERE  ( r5.revisionstatus = 2 )) tbl4 
                            ON tbl1.dataid = tbl4.asm_dataid 
        WHERE  ( EXISTS (SELECT b.dataid 
                         FROM   dtreeacl b 
                         WHERE  b.dataid = Nvl(tbl2.permid, tbl2.lldataid) 
                                AND ( rightid IN ( -2, -1, 1000, 1001 ) ) 
                                AND see > 0) ) 
        ORDER  BY modified_date DESC) tbl100 
WHERE  rownum <= 25
```

> ORACLE SQL Developer throws an error as: ORA-00907: missing right
>   parenthesis

It looks like everything is fine but don't understand where am I getting the error of missing right parenthesis.

Comment: If you are using sqldevelopper, I suggest you to excecut each join statement separately to see where the issue is coming from. Sometimes the error make no sense because you forgot "as" or comma before the end of parenthesis.

Comment: 17 left and 17 right pathernesis.

Comment: I copied the query into SQL Developer, and it gave the line and column of the error. `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 42 Column: 53`. It's the `Cast(d.dcomment AS NVARCHAR(4000))`. It seems you don't use a size when you cast last NVARCHAR. Remove the (4000).

Comment: AT is a reserved word at least in ANSI SQL, change that alias to something else, or double quote, i.e. "at".

Comment: `Cast(d.dcomment AS NVARCHAR(4000))` NVARCHAR or NVARCHAR2? also whats the type of dcomment?

Answer (score 0):

It is all because of `Cast(d.dcomment AS NVARCHAR(4000))`. NVARCHAR is not a valid data type.

Change it to `Cast(d.dcomment AS NVARCHAR2(2000))`

It will work

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/746)

In the fiddle my sample is

```
select Cast('ddd' AS NVARCHAR2(2000)) AS dd from dual
```

If you change it in to

```
select Cast('ddd' AS NVARCHAR(2000)) AS dd from dual
```

You will get the error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

[Cast Operator in Oracle Tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php)

[Data Types in Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php)